# how to clone UEFI bootable USB disk onto another disk (possibly of different size)

Tags: boot, uefi, usb-drive, clone

How can I clone my existing UEFI bootable disk, so that the copy is identical?

I have tried creating new bootable disk, using same procedure, same label name, and same UUID and PARTUUID labels for the GPT partition, yet in my laptop's boot menu, it shows every single boot device I have ever booted from, as separate entry.

I cannot simply cat one disk image onto another disk, because the USB disks are different sizes.

How can I clone everything from one bootable disk onto another one?

Where is the identifier that UEFI boot uses , stored ?

why is the UEFI design so idiotic, that my boot menu remembers every device i have ever booted from? How can I delete the list?

Comment: how your UEFI menu looks is a specific implementation of your mainboard vendor, and nothing anyone else could change.

Comment: Could this help : https://www.kolmann.at/2017/06/clone-uefi-booted-debian-linux/ ?

Comment: `why is the UEFI design so idiotic` perhaps that's unique to your laptop/motherboard - I have over a dozen computers and not one of them exhibits that idiotic behaviour

Comment: `because the USB disks are different sizes` if the destination is bigger, there is no issue. If the destination is smaller, then perhaps something like clonezilla could be helpful

Comment: `How can I delete the list?` The `efibootmgr` command is your friend - `efibootmgr -v` to view the list, identify the four-digit hex number of the entry you wish to delete, and then `efibootmgr -b XXXX -B` where XXXX is the entry number, to delete the entry. For idiotic UEFI user interface design, complain to your hardware vendor: unfortunately most vendors of consumer-grade systems seem to have done their best to actively make UEFI look "just like a legacy BIOS" which throws away any advantages.

Comment: @telcoM - I had no problems with legacy bios. But the UEFI design is idiotic and over complicated and confusing, as one would expect from anything designed by Microsoft.

Comment: Why do you want an exact duplicate. You cannot reboot with both installed as duplicate UUIDs & GUIDs are not allowed. Usually better to just do new install & rsync your data & /home configurations. Microsoft did not create UEFI. It was EFI and then EFI became version 1 or UEFI standard. Apple used EFI for years before Microsoft adopted it in 2012. External drives boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi or drive (name or label) entry, not "ubuntu". And most UEFI delete or modify UEFI entry when drive disconnected, so specific drive entry would remain when drive removed, but not work.

Comment: @MartinVegter I'd be more careful throwing around words like "idiotic" and "over complicated", especially when you evidently haven't understood how EFI works yet.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've written, you've missed the most important part:

UEFI will search for a boot loader named by default `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` *(case insensitive)* on the EFI partition.  The disk must be partitioned with a GPT partition table and the EFI partition has a **type** UUID `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B`.  EFI is formatted FAT32.

You can use a simple partitioning tool `cfdisk` to set the partition type, or `sfdisk` if you are feeling particularly brave.  Use `mkfs.vfat` to format it.  The UUID and PARTUUID of the EFI partition rarely get used for much on boot, but they may be used in your system's `/etc/fstab` to mount the EFI partition.

Other file names inside the EFI partition are also possible, but not practical for a bootable USB because you need to inform your firmware about them manually.

*I suspect you just forgot to set the partition type, or otherwise inadvertently formatted with the wrong FS type.*

---

Unlike legacy boot, UEFI bootable devices are much easier to copy, since there's no program code hidden on the disk, it's all in files in mountable file systems.

The only trick is, like legacy boot systems, you might need to preserve UUID and PARTUUID so that linux knows what to mount where.

So cloning a disk onto a smaller one can be as simple as:

- partition the new disk
- format the partitions with the same FS types
- copy the files
- (re)set the UUID and PARTUUID on the partitions

---

> why is the UEFI design so idiotic, that my boot menu remembers every device i have ever booted from? How can I delete the list?

That's not part of the UEFI specification and seems to be a fault with your specific firmware.

Comment: sorry, but that does no answer the main question: I have created 2 UEFI boot disks, with same label `Test` and identical UUID and PARTUUID. Yet, they report as distinct 2 disks: `Boot002B* Test` and `Boot002C* Test`. Therefore, there is somewhere some identifier `Boot002B* Test`. How do I clone this identifier, so that both disk are identical?

Comment: @MartinVegter UEFI boot entries are usually not on per-disk basis, especially not if they are "static" entries that got written to the NVRAM upon e.g. bootloader / boot manager installation, so theoretically/technically (AFAIK) it is possible to have multiple entries that have identical content. Also, for "dynamic" entries that get created for EFI executables at the "fallback" path at least, often the entries don't just have PARTUUID, but also the "device path" of the drive. If you want further help, you should probably add full output of `efibootmgr`.

Comment: @MartinVegter if you are trying to make it so that one disk is recognised as if it's another by your UEFI firmware then that would be off topic for this site as it's a UEFI problem not a Linux one and you are not describing common UEFI behaviour. You'd need to ask over on superuser.com and be very specific about which firmware you are having a problem with. There's a small chance it's the GPT table's own UUID that's getting recognised. I doubt that Boot002c is stored on the disk, that sounds like an autogenerated name by UEFI.